# Ownership of static fields & methods in Java

Tags: java, class, static-methods

I'd like to ask a question about classes and the "mechanism", via which Java loads them on memory, particularly regarding the creation of static fields and methods.

A class may have static fields and methods that can be called from the class itself when loaded, without the need to create an instance of the class. How does it happen ?? What is the "mechanism" behind it ??

I know that when JVM needs to load a class, it creates a class object containing metadata on how to create instances of the respective class. But when static fields and methods are also loaded, are they assigned to the class object, for instance, and it, in return, creates a reference for them for each new instance created ?? Is this what explains how a static method can be invoked from both the class (whatever that may mean in an *object* oriented language) as well as each instance of it ?? No matter how hard I google it, i can't find an answer on how things work in this particular matter.

On top of that, does anyone know why Java allows access to static fields from the instances, as well as the "class itself"?? What is the concept, I mean.

Thanks beforehand to all of you for your time.

Comment: They're stored in memory, just like any other memory.

Comment: Reference statics from an instance is just a compiler silliness and has nothing to do with the runtime.

Comment: Every object has a reference to its own class, and it gets the static items via that reference, not via extra references to each static item. That's also why referencing a static from an object reference works. It's not just 'compiler silliness' (@SLaks). It is in fact unavoidable.

Comment: @EJP: No; writing `new Foo().someStaticMethod()` is pure syntax sugar.

Comment: @SLaks Using a reference opens the entire scope of the class it refers to. Removing statics from that scope for this purpose would take extra work. It doesn't take more work. It is not 'syntactic sugar'.

Comment: @EJP: I have no idea what you mean.  Are you talking about the parser? `new Foo().someStaticMethod()` and `Foo.someStaticMethod()` should compile to identical bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the concept of class loading and linking. It's explained very well here [jvmspec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4)

Especially section

> 5.3. Creation and Loading

You may want to check out the [jvm architecture](https://dzone.com/articles/jvm-architecture-explained)  as well. It gives a better understanding of the method area which is used to store class level information such as static variables and methods.

Comment: Maybe I am not asking it properly. When one creates an object of a class, its fields are "associated" to it, so they are called as follows : myobj.field . However, when a class is loaded, its static fields and methods are also loaded without any object being created. So, in object oriented programming, when we write MyClass.static_field , what is the class _on memory_, from which static fields are called ?? A class is a blueprint, from which a "class obj" is created by JVM to contain metadata for future instances . 

So,what are static fields called FROM ?? That is the question

Comment: (cont.) I mean, an object is a structure on RAM that contains its fields and methods. What is a class on RAM ?? It is not a structure like an object, from which calls to its (static) fields can happen, so what is the meaning of MyClass.static_field ??

Comment: @VBent Instances of the class [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) represent classes and interfaces in a running Java application.